# send cUrl requests in function with functions parameters by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, function, curl

i want send cUrl requests in function with function parameters by Ajax.

this is my cUrl requests:

```
function cUrlConnection ($url, $username, $password, $ch) {

        $pass = md5($password);

        $data = array( 
            'username' => $username,
            'password'=> $pass,

        );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl; rv:1.8.0.4) Gecko/20060426 Firefox/1.5.0.4');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '40');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $pos = strpos($result, "התחברת בהצלחה");

        if ($pos === false) {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return $ch;
        }
    }
$chs = cUrlConnection($url, $username, $password, $ch);
```

i want send the variable $chs with function, to another file by Ajax.
how i'm do this?

Comment: please use at start $ch = curl_init($url); you have not initialized $ch

Comment: it's right, i'm added this, but here i'm hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this(as using array like this makes it multipart form posting):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

into:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```